# SharePoint fast search creating filters automatically

Tags: fast

I've created a FAST Search Center and found that during a search a filter has been automatically created for "company".

I've checked the managed meta data store and the local term set store but its not defined in any of those lists, nor is it defined anywhere else I can find it.

Weirdly its able to pick up a "company" in a document with no meta data associated, no extra list properties filled out and no document properties filled in...

How is this happening/Where is this managed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The company extractor has some internal dictionaries as well as logic to pick up company names. You can also add your own inclusions and exclusions via Central Admin.

But, as you noticed, it is not using the managed metadata store.

There is also a person name and location extraction in place if you want to use those - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff795826.aspx#optional-item-proc-property